# Deriving cross product from angular momentum algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, vectors, lie-algebra

Is it possible to derive:
\begin{equation}
\hat{L}=\hat{r}\times \hat{p}
\end{equation}
from the angular momentum algebra:
\begin{equation}
[\hat{L}_i,\hat{L}_j]=i\ \hbar\ \epsilon_{ijk}\hat{L}_k\ ?
\end{equation}
I have read somewhere that commutation relations of the form
\begin{equation}
[a_i,b_j]=\epsilon_{ijk} c_k
\end{equation}
admit a "natural rewriting in terms of cross products", but there weren't any details about this statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to derive the orbital angular momentum $L = r \times p$ from the $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ commutation relations alone, since the spin operator $S$ also fulfills the same commutation relations, but certainly is different from $r \times p$.

Comment: That's exactly what I would have written, but I don't know if more needs to be said to explain why or how we know that spin is different.

Answer (score 7):

> I have read somewhere that commutation relations of the form
>   \begin{equation} [a_i,b_j]=\epsilon_{ijk} c_k \end{equation} admit a
>   "natural rewriting in terms of cross products", but there weren't any
>   details about this statement.

This "natural rewriting" of the canonical commutation relations for angular momenta in term of cross products is:
$$
\vec J \times \vec J = i\vec J
$$

I.e., the "natural rewriting" refers to rewriting the commutation relations themselves in terms of a cross product, not rewriting a single angular momentum in terms of cross products of other quantities.

Explicitly, for angular momentum:
$$
\vec J \times \vec J = i\vec J
$$
Thus:
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}J_jJ_k=iJ_i
$$
Thus:
$$
\epsilon_{ilm}\epsilon_{ijk}J_jJ_k=i\epsilon_{ilm}J_i
$$
Thus:
$$
J_lJ_m-J_mJ_l=i\epsilon_{ilm}J_i
$$
I.e.:
$$
[J_l,J_m]=i\epsilon_{lmi}J_i
$$

In terms of your "a", "b", and "c", the analogous "natural rewriting" is:
$$
\vec a\times \vec b + \vec b \times \vec a=2\vec c
$$

You can see this by considering:
$$
(\vec a \times \vec b)_i
=\epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k=\epsilon_{ijk}(b_ka_j+[a_j,b_k])
$$
$$
=-\epsilon_{ikj}b_ka_j+\epsilon_{ijk}[a_j,b_k]
$$
$$
=-(\vec b \times \vec a)_i+\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{jkl}c_l
$$
$$
=-(\vec b\times\vec a)_i+2\delta_{il}c_l
$$
$$
=(-\vec b\times \vec a +2c)_i
$$

Comment: How is $[a_l,b_m]=a_lb_m-a_mb_l$?

Comment: whoops, good question... screwed that up somehow... Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} 
\left[\hat{A}_{i}, \hat{B}_{j} \right] & = \epsilon_{ijk}\hat{C}_{k}, \\[3mm]
\hat{A}_{i}\hat{B}_{j} - \hat{B}_{j}\hat{A}_{i} & = \epsilon_{ijk}\hat{C}_{k}, \\[3mm]
\epsilon_{ijn}\left( \hat{A}_{i}\hat{B}_{j} - \hat{B}_{j}\hat{A}_{i}\right) & = \epsilon_{ijn}\epsilon_{ijk}\hat{C}_{k}, \\[3mm]
\epsilon_{ijn}\hat{A}_{i}\hat{B}_{j} - \epsilon_{ijn}\hat{B}_{j}\hat{A}_{i} & = 2\hat{C}_{n}, \\[3mm]
\left(\hat{\vec{A}} \times \hat{\vec{B}}\right)_{n} + \left(\hat{\vec{B}} \times \hat{\vec{A}}\right)_{n} & = 2\hat{C}_{n}, \\[3mm]
\frac{1}{2}\left(\hat{\vec{A}} \times \hat{\vec{B}} + \hat{\vec{B}} \times \hat{\vec{A}} \right) & = \hat{\vec{C}}.
\end{align}$$
due to the fact that $\epsilon_{ijn}\epsilon_{ijk} = 2\delta_{nk}$.

Comment: What is wrong with this derivation?

Comment: Besides the fact that sometime you explicitly write the summations and sometimes they are implicit, there's nothing wrong with the derivation. Probably people are down-voting because there is no explanatory text to go along with the equations... or maybe the explicit/implicit thing is confusing...